# Stack Level Too Deep - Re: has_many to belongs_to Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here's my code:

```
#class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end

#class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :task_list

#TaskList < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
```

With a `category_id` in the TaskList model.

I'm putting this in my view:

```
<%= @category.task_list.id %>
```

And I get a `stack level too deep` error.

I'm lost and I swear I've done this same setup 100 times over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

### Update:

Here's the full trace (minus the top i trimmed cause it was repeating over and over again:

```
See gist link below
```

### Update 2:

Ok I've started from scratch and refined somethings I didn't need and am doing this exactly as it shows: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

#_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <% f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>  
        <p>  
            <%= builder.text_field :name %>  
        </p>  
        <% end %>  

    </p>

    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>

#CategoryController 
def new
  @category = Category.new
  3.times { @category.tasks.build }  
end
```

And I'm still getting the same thing... Here's the full https://gist.github.com/1185772

### Update 3:

Here's the full version of the Task & Category models: https://gist.github.com/1185839

Comment: trace? It sounds like you may have a recursive loop, but my intuition tells me it isn't in the snippet you provided.

Comment: Added the full trace and took off the top lines that were repeating over and over again.

Comment: Do the models really have no other code beside these relations? Are the classes defined in the proper files (`app/models/task.rb` and `app/models/category.rb`)?

Comment: There is more... https://gist.github.com/1185839 ... I didn't include it all because even when I comment out the rest in the models it still does the same thing.

Comment: This probably is completely unrelated, but I'm pretty sure acts_as_tree adds scopes for parent and children (in the form of associations)

Comment: Also, you still must be leaving something out. I don't see this anywhere `app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:14:in `new'
app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:14:in `times'
app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:14:in `new'`

Comment: actually that was the problem... the acts_as_tree... arg. thanks man!

Answer (score 8):

Have you checked your models?

If both are set to :destroy, then you'll end up with an infinite loop and the stack level too deep error. They should be as follows:

```
has_one :task_list, :dependent => :destroy

belongs_to :category, :dependent => :delete
```

There's more info. about the error [here](http://mo.morsi.org/blog/node/282).

Comment: What if I want Categories to be dependent though and not need a task_list?

Added the full trace and took off the top lines that were repeating over and over again.

Comment: Actually even when I do this I still get the same response. Stack level too deep and the trace is the same.

Comment: Check out the new update. I've started from scratch and I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: YES this is the answer for me.

I have: `A has_many B through C:
B has_one A through C:
C belongs_to A and B.`
I want to destroy the B's and C's when I destroy an A, but only destroy the C's when I destroy the B. The answer, as you have given.

Answer (score 1):

See the comment that diedthreetimes left on the question. Acts_as_tree was having an issue with the scopes that I had made. And I also ended up starting from scratch and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `task` is a reserved word in Rails. Here is what `task` output when executing in a clean app console:

```
irb(main):001:0> task
=> <Rake::Task  => []>
```

Rename your model and it will work.

Comment: I am almost sure that this is not the problem. _Scope_ ensures that you may safely use `task` as a method or variable name.

Comment: But I've been able to do the exact thing before on another rails app with a Project model and a Task model. Or is it in Rails 3 that you can't use 'Task'? ---- I changed the model name to tix_task and it didn't change anything unforunately

Answer (score 0):

Your gist shows Tasks < ActiveRecord when it should be Task < ActiveRecord

Did you generate your model properly like so:

```
rails g model Task category_id:integer title:string
```

Comment: This might not solve your stack too deep problem but it is still an error unless the gist is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. When cicloon said that I had to change the model name, I changed it to something else, but I must not have renamed it back properly when I changed it back to task. Nevertheless... I'm still getting the same error.... and yes that is how I created the model except I used nifty-scaffold.

Comment: When you changed the model name, did you migrate the database to match it? Make sure your database has the correct table names tasks and categories.  Also, are you in your production or development environment?

Comment: All of that is good. I'm in development. I just created a new model, named project, just the same (as far as I can still) as the category model and it works. So something is up with the Category model. I might just redo the Category model from scratch... which will be annoying cause it's filled with info but it's ok.

Comment: Cool, glad you found something to get you back on track.